# How do you know who are dependent on the project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have solution with 30+ projects, so they are have many references.
I have one project into solution. And want to know who are dependent on this project?

Thank you!

Comment: If your solution was able to build without the new project, then none of the existing projects depends on the new project!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are broadly two ways to accomplish this.

First, if you right-click the project (or solution) and select **Project Dependencies** you can see a list of dependencies for each project. This gets you *"Which projects does project X depend on"* but not easily *"Which projects depend on project X"*.

Alternately, if you happen to have Visual Studio Ultimate you can right-click your .sln file and select **[Show on Code Map](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/11/08/code-maps-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)**. This is a much more comprehensive way of visualising dependencies in your solution (namespace- and type-level as well as project-level), but sadly isn't available in lower editions of Visual Studio.

Alternately, both [ndepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) and [Resharper](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/06/13/resharper-8-architecture-tools/) both provide third-party ways of visualising dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project and choose **Project Dependencies** option.

[image]